# Translate image using PIL for Deep Learning

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, data-augmentation

I am using Pillow in order to achieve data augmentation on a dataset for a road recognition neural network. I wanted to do a translation (say left to right) on my satellite picture, while transferring the rightmost side of the image (which would be outside of the boundaries) to the leftside, as if you were playing pacman, in order not to lose any information.

I thought about using `PIL.Image.AFFINE` transform as such :

```py
    import PIL

    def TranslateX(img)
        return img.transform(img.size, PIL.Image.AFFINE, (1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
```

which does transform the following image [the following image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8O28t.jpg) into [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vasd5.jpg) (you can see the black border on the left side) but does not give a satisfying result which would rather look [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjc0O.png)

Am I missing something ? Does anyone have any idea as to how I could achieve this ?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Not too sure I have understood Pacman, satellites and cartoon figures but I think you want to flip the image left-right using **PIL**'s `Image.transform()`

Comment: Can you describe the actual output that you want to get. I didn't quite understood what is the output you are expecting.

Comment: For clarification : I want to have the part of the image that was cut-out by the translation on the right side coming back on the left side, which would look something like this : https://i.imgur.com/TmWMXmj.png

Comment: Oh, you need to **roll** the image... https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/tutorial.html?highlight=Roll#rolling-an-image

Answer (score 1):

Answer provided by Mark Setchel (thank you!)

Turns out I just needed to **roll** my image... Again, words are important when asking a question.
see the doc : https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/tutorial.html?highlight=Roll#rolling-an-image